# How to open FrameMaker files on a Mac with OS X?

Tags: file-conversion, applications

I have some old [FrameMaker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FrameMaker) documents on my Mac (Intel Core Duo, OS X 1.6.6). Is there any way to open this files (readonly would be ok)? I cannot use the FrameMaker 10 trial from Adobe, because it is windows only. There has been a reader/viewer app in the past but I cannot find it anywhere.

There are two file formats:

- `*.mif` is Maker Interchange Format (an XML dialect)
- `*.fm` is FrameMaker binary

Comment: Suffering from the same I couldn't find another solution yet than the DTP-Filters (available for InDesign or Quark XPress) that allows to import and work on MIF/FM-Files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe provides an online pdf creator which they state handles FrameMaker files.

However, it costs $10 a month to use it, but it might be worth a shot. (Albeit, you may convert 5 files to pdfs before you have to pay).

http://createpdf.adobe.com

Comment: I do not find any hint that CreatePDF handles FrameMaker, but I will have a try with the test account...

Comment: http://createpdf.adobe.com/cgi-feeder.pl/formats?BP=&LOC=en_US
"Adobe Formats
Illustrator® (.ai), InDesign™ (.indd), FrameMaker® (.fm, .mif), PageMaker® (.pm, .pm6, .p65, .pmd, .pmt), Photoshop® (.psd)"

Comment: Thanks, the FAQ does not list it: https://createpdf.acrobat.com/faq.html

Comment: Arrrgghh. There a two versions of the createpdf service: createpdf.adobe.com and createpdf.acrobat.com. The acrobat version does not work (upload does not allow *.fm, point to printer driver but that is wirndows 7 only). But I have uploaded to the adobe site and got the pdf by email!

Comment: Unfortunately the website createpdf.adobe.com now forwards you to createpdf.acrobat.com.
It seems as if Adobe does not provide anymore a service for Framemaker to PDF conversion.

Answer (score 0):

[MIF Filter](http://www.dtptools.com/product.asp?id=mfid)

From DTP Tools. [IDNWFT](http://jasonology.posterous.com/i-do-not-work-for-them)

Comment: Sounds good, but I do not have InDesign.

Answer (score 0):

Find a friend with a Windows system and get them to download the (fully functional) 30-day trial.

Or, set up Bootcamp/Parallels and do the same on your system.